# Speed up Nodemailer send Emails

Tags: javascript, nodemailer, netlify

I've got a NodeJS code something like this:
(Netlify)

```
const sendEmail = require('./sendmail')
async function checkout() {
    try {
        await someFunction()
    } catch(e) {}
    try {
        await someOtherFunction()
    } catch(e) {}
    try {
        await sendEmail.sendCustomer(subject, body, to)  // await or not?
        await sendEmail.sendOurself(subject, body, to)   // await or not?
    }
    finally {
        return {
            statusCode: 200
        }
    }
}
```

And the function to send Emails:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
async function sendEmail(subject, body, to) {

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: HOST,
        port: PORT,
        secure: SECURE,
        auth: { user: AUTH.user, pass: AUTH.pass,}
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: AUTH.user,
        to: to,
        subject: subject,
        html: body,
    };

    return await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
};

exports.sendEmail = sendEmail
```

Problem is, the function to send emails, takes forever. sometimes 5 seconds, sometimes up to 12 seconds for both Emails.

How could I speed this up? As you can see, I don't really care about the response from nodemailer. So I tried to removed the await in the last try-block and made the function sendEmail synchronous. But then, the emails doesn't get sent. I think it's because the function stops running when I return 200.  How could I speed up this process?

Comment: The reason why not awaiting does not send the mail is because the serverless function gets killed after it returns or something similar... On a "normal" nodeJs server, this would certainly not be a problem, but on Netlify, that's another story, if you do not await the process simply does not have the time to send the mail before it gets stoped. I'm adding netlify tag so you get more help from people who know that.

Answer (score -1):

I've ended up with Promise.all instead of awaiting.

Comment: Here's hoping you don't get banned from your mail server!

Comment: @AKX
I'm not sending a Newsletter to thousands of people. I only send periodically two at the time when someone fills out a form.